# How to hook __usercall, __userpurge (__spoils) functions?

Tags: c, hook, reverse-engineering, detours, usercall

Know anybody something about hooking `__usercall` type of functions?
I hooking successfully `__thiscall`, `__stdcall` and `__cdecl` calls but this is enough for me.

Know anybody hooking library for `__usercall`'s or how to hook this type of functions using translation to `__stdcall` or `__cdecl`?

Function what i must hook at first is:

```
int __usercall func<eax>(int a<eax>, int b<ecx>, int c, unsigned int d, signed int e);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a wrapper which will convert it to `__stdcall`.

```
int __stdcall func_hook_payload(int a, int b, int c, unsigned int d, signed int e);

// Wrapper for
// int __usercall func<eax>(int a<eax>, int b<ecx>, int c, unsigned int d, signed int e);
__declspec(naked) void func_hook()
{__asm{
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push dword ptr[ebp + 0x0C] // or just push e
    push dword ptr[ebp + 0x08] // d
    push dword ptr[ebp + 0x04] // c
    push ecx // b
    push eax // a
    call func_hook_payload
    leave
    ret // note: __usercall is cdecl-like
}}
```

Comment: you are sure of working this? You not should `pop` arguments from detoured function callee?

Comment: @Svisstack: yes, I'm sure. Just try it.

Comment: i trying, but maybe something is wrong maybe in my second wrapper __stdcall to __usercall, debugger says access violation after calling original usercall function (becasue i must have result) hmm propably i doing something wrong with arguments.

Comment: can you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102981/what-is-wrong-with-this-usercall-wrapper ?

Comment: Abyx how should I call this? by func_hook_payload? or func_hook? I never seen a function inside of a function like that.

Comment: @SSpoke: it's *hook* function (callback). Program will call it, not you.

Answer (score 2):

When all else fails.. walk through it with a debugger.

In particular take note of these like the ESP when you enter the call, and then again just before the function returns..