# How to hook/convert __userpurge func to __stdcall or __cdecl?

Tags: c, hook, reverse-engineering, detours, userpurge

Know anybody something about hooking `__userpurge` type of functions?
I hooking successfully `__thiscall`, `__stdcall`, `__cdecl`, `__usercall`.

How to hook this type of functions using translation to `__stdcall` or `__cdecl`?

Function who i must hook at first is:

```
int __userpurge func<eax>(int a1<ecx>, char a2<dil>, int a3, int a4)
```

Comment: What is `__userpurge` defined to?

Comment: What is that question about? certainly not C. Please tag your question correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idadoc/1361.shtml) documentation, `__userpurge` is the same as `__usercall`, except the callee cleans up the stack. Do as suggested in your previous question ([How to hook __usercall, __userpurge (__spoils) functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099026/how-to-hook-usercall-userpurge-spoils-functions)), and leave stack cleanup to your callee.